# Angular 2 no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ionic, ionic2, cordova-plugin, angular

Tenho estado a trabalhar num projecto que usa Ionic Framework e AngularJS para mobile e utilizo o Visual Studio 2015 "Tools for Cordova" para fazer build e debug ao projecto.

Recentemente, o Angular 2 e o Ionic 2 saíram em versão estável e decidi começar a fazer migração do projecto actual para as frameworks mais recentes.

Reparei que o Visual Studio ainda não tem muito suporte para Angular 2 e então decidi usar "Angular 2 CLI" para criar um projecto em Angular 2 e depois fazer import como projecto Cordova.

Apresenta alguns problemas de referencias no TypeScript. Existe alguma maneira de passar o meu projecto angularJS 1 para o 2 a partir do Visual Studio?

Algum link que me possa ajudar.

Comment: Bom dia É possível migrar projeto Angular 1.x para Angular 2. Segue o link da documentação do Framework https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Comment: acredito que se usar o visual studio code vai ser melhor para gerir a migração para o angular 2 - https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 1):

Acabei por usar Visual Studio Code, é fácil de fazer a migração e temos as ferramentas disponíveis para o desenvolvimento.

Tem optimas extensões para facilitar o desenvolvimento de código em snippets como o "Angular TypeScript Snippets" e extensões Git para controlo de versões.

É fácil de usar, é mais leve e é organizado. Sendo que toda a compilação passa pelo Node.JS.